# update dataframe with another with duplicated index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update a dataframe according to another. I try to use df.update the issue that the index can be duplicated which raise the error : `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

any idea how to do it?

For example:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'ticket': ['a','b','c'], 'n': ['10','20','30'], 
                   'q': ['100','120','130'],'description': ['da','db','dc']})
```

[image]

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'ticket': ['a','a','b'], 'n': ['40','50','60'], 
                   'q': ['150','180','200']})
```

[image]

The expected result would be

```
pd.DataFrame({'ticket': ['a','a','b','c'], 'n': ['40','50','60', '30'], 
              'q': ['150','180','200','130'], 'description': ['da','da','db','dc']})
```

[image]

I try this
`d1.set_index('ticket', inplace=True)
d1.update(d2.set_index('ticket'))` but raise the above error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets try [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with `set_index` and `reindex` to get desired column order:

```
final=(d2.set_index('ticket').combine_first(d1.set_index('ticket'))
                  .reset_index().reindex(columns=d1.columns))
```

---

```
  ticket   n    q description
0      a  40  150          da
1      a  50  180          da
2      b  60  200          db
3      c  30  130          dc
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought combine first only update null values?

Comment: @anky - why did you switch the order of dataframes when using combine_first? is it because d1 has unique ticket values while d2 has duplicate ticket values? would combine_first work if both d1 and d2 have duplicate ticket values?

Comment: @KrishSrinivasan it is not recommended for non unique values. Combine first works best with unique index values. For Duplicate values, make a helper column with `df.groupby.cumcount()` and then use both the original column and the helper column in the merge (df.merge....)